# Sample size calculation to compare results with max accepted values

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, descriptive-statistics

I have to make an chemistry study about the lead (Pb, plumbum) contained by tomatoes inside a tomato farm, but I'm having throuble to estimate the sample size. Is there any formula to calculate the sample size?(asuming that i have to):

- Pick the tomatoes samples from the farm.
- Identify the tomatoes kind (not relevant for the lead measurement).
- Measure the lead in the tomatoes selected.
- Compare the measurements with the maximun lead allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all of those things with any sample size greater than zero. The reason the sample size matters for this is that the larger the sample, the more accurately you can estimate the distribution of lead across all tomatoes. A rule of thumb in data analysis is that samples don't have to be a certain minimum size (beyond the low bar required for identifiability), but larger samples are more informative.